# Sum of product of all subarray of length less than equal to k

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Given array of integers with size `n` called `A`. Find the sum of product of all possible subarrays from `A` with the length less than `k` with modulo `M`. e.g.

```
A = [9 1 90]
k = 2
M = 10
```

then the asked sum will be:

```
sum = (9 + 1 + 90 + (9 * 1) + (1 * 90)) % 10 = 9
```

I first tried a simple dynamic programming as long as an iteration over the `A` and it took O(nk) and it got time limit error. The mentioned code in cpp is as follows:

```cpp
int main() {
    int n, k, M;
    cin >> n >> k >> M;
    long long int D[n][n];
    int sum_ = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        temp %= M;
        D[i][i] = temp;
        sum_ = ((sum_ + temp) % M);
    }

    for (size_t t = 1; t < k; t++)
    {
        size_t i = 0, j = t;
        while (j < n) {
            int mid = (i + j) / 2;
            int temp = (D[i][mid] * D[mid+1][j]) % M;
            D[i][j] = temp;
            sum_ = ((sum_ + (temp % M)) % M);
            i ++;
            j ++;
        }
        
    }
    cout << sum_ << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So now I'm thinking of maybe a Divide and Conquer method to solve it in O(nlogn) but I can not come up with any good solution.

Is there any way to solve this problem in a better time complexity of O(nk) (or O(n.n)).

Comment: create a prefix product array out of `A`. Then move a window of size `k` over the prefix product array from the previous step and sum the result of each window. All of this is done in `O(n)` time and space.

Comment: I'd suggest using the distributive property of multiplication. Assuming `k < n`, we have that `A[0]` and `A[n - 1]` appear in exactly `k` subarrays (of size smaller than or equal to `k`). Figuring out `cnt_i`, the number of subarrays `A[i]` appears for each index `i`, is up to the reader. From here, the answer would be `sum(cnt_i * A[i]) % M`, which will likely have to be split up due to size constraints on integers.

Answer (score 1):

We can write a solution with `O(n)` complexity using dynamic programming.

First we define dp[i] as sum of product of all subarrays of length less than or equal to k starting at ith position in array A.
We also define b[i] as the product of the subarray of length k starting from the ith position in array A (if i<=n-k) and as the product of the subarray starting from ith position and ending at the nth position (if i>=n-k).

We can easily determine that `b[i] = ((b[i+1] * a[i]) / (a[i+k])) % M` if(i+k<=n) and `b[i] = (b[i+1] * a[i]) % M` if(i+k>n).

We can also determine that `dp[i] = (a[i] * (dp[i+1]-b[i+1]) + a[i]) % M` if(i+k<=n) and `dp[i]= (a[i] * dp[i+1] + a[i]) % M` if (i+k>n)

The answer to the question would be the sum of `dp[i]` for `1<=i<=n`

Thus the complexity would be `O(n)`.